# what's the difference between (let b = MyBox(5 as *const u8); &b; )and (let b = &MyBox(5 as *const u8); ) in rust

Tags: rust

first:

```rust
use std::thread;
use std::sync::Arc;
use std::sync::Mutex;
#[derive(Debug)]
struct MyBox(*const u8);
unsafe impl Send for MyBox {}
unsafe impl Sync for MyBox {}

fn main() {
    let b = &MyBox(5 as *const u8);
    let v = Arc::new(Mutex::new(b));
    let t = thread::spawn(move || {
        let _v1 =  v.lock().unwrap();
    });
    t.join().unwrap();
}
```

second:

```rust
use std::thread;
use std::sync::Arc;
use std::sync::Mutex;
#[derive(Debug)]
struct MyBox(*const u8);
unsafe impl Send for MyBox {}
unsafe impl Sync for MyBox {}

fn main() {
    let b = MyBox(5 as *const u8);
    let v = Arc::new(Mutex::new(&b));
    let t = thread::spawn(move || {
        let _v1 =  v.lock().unwrap();
    });
    t.join().unwrap();
}
```

first will be .but second :`b` does not live long enough borrowed value does not live long enough
what's wrong here? They are both MyBox reference.

Comment: Your explanation seems disjointed. Did you inadvertently drop and/or repeat some words in "first will be .but second :b does not live long enough borrowed value does not live long enough"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The expression `MyBox(5 as *const u8)` is made up of only constants (and a few other criteria) and thus can be [const promoted](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/reference/destructors.html#constant-promotion). So when you create `b` as a reference, the value can actually be put in static storage and so `b` is a `&'static MyBox`.

In the second case, when `b` is not a reference, it won't use static storage since `b` is unarguably a local variable and thus has function-local storage. So a reference to that value cannot satisfy the `'static` lifetime that `thread::spawn` requires.

As a side note, you should use [`thread::scope`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/thread/fn.scope.html) when you want to create threads that can reference local variables.

Comment: The actual error message thrown for the second code is completely unrelated to the `'static` requirement of `thread::spawn()`. The code won't compile even if you remove all mentions of `thread`. The borrow `&b` only lives until the end of the statement, so it can't be moved into a `Mutex` that lives longer than that.